# ADDIMGCLG through FTP results in an error status for virtual upload

Tags: ftp, ibm-midrange

I have a batch file that works well until the LODIMGCLG command. At which pint gives me an error of 550-Error occurred on command...
I went to my AS400 command line and typed it in and got a message that No image catalog entries in loaded status. I did a WRKIMGCLGE and saw that my .iso  file has an Error as the status. Also, when trying to access my folders on the ifs, I am receiving permission issues. This may be part of the issue, but I can't figure out why I get either of these issues

```
@echo off

SET /P release= Please enter in release number: 

if EXIST ftpcmd2.dat goto :justRunIt

SET /P userpw= Please enter in AHC password: 
SET /P IPaddr= Please enter in IP address of the AS400: 

 >ftpcmd2.dat echo.open %IPaddr% 
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.user
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.ahc
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.%userpw% 
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.bin
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.quote rcmd LODIMGCLG IMGCLG(AHCUPD) OPTION(*UNLOAD)
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.quote rcmd RMVIMGCLGE IMGCLG(AHCUPD) IMGCLGIDX(1) KEEP(*NO)
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.quote rcmd DLTIMGCLG IMGCLG(AHCUPD) KEEP(*NO) DEPIMGCLG(*DELETE)
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.quote rcmd VRYCFG CFGOBJ(OPTVRT03) CFGTYPE(*DEV) STATUS(*OFF) FRCVRYOFF(*YES)
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.quote rcmd DLTDEVD DEVD(OPTVRT03) 
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.cd /
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.mkdir Global
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.cd Global
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.mkdir %release%
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.cd %release%
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.lcd c:\ahc
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.put Update%release%.iso
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.quote rcmd CRTDEVOPT DEVD(OPTVRT03) RSRCNAME(*VRT) TEXT('Virtual CD/DVD Device for Global')
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.quote rcmd VRYCFG CFGOBJ(OPTVRT03) CFGTYPE(*DEV) STATUS(*ON) RANGE(*OBJ)
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.quote rcmd CRTIMGCLG IMGCLG(AHCUPD) DIR('/UPDATE2') CRTDIR(*YES) TEXT('Image catalog for AHC Updates') AUT(*ALL)
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.quote rcmd ADDIMGCLGE IMGCLG(AHCUPD) FROMFILE('/GLOBAL/%RELEASE%/UPDATE%RELEASE%.iso')
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.quote rcmd LODIMGCLG IMGCLG(AHCUPD) OPTION(*LOAD) DEV(OPTVRT03)
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.quote LODRUN DEV(OPT03)

:justRunIt
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd2.dat
```

Comment: Seems to me it shouldn't load an image catalog that is in error status. You probably need to work that out first.

Comment: Start by looking into QAUDJRN to find entries related to your processes. From there, you should be able to track to root causes. IMO, these commands should be restricted from FTP (ideally because any profile authorized to them should be rejected by FTP).